# vera++ throw error: cannot open profile description for profile default

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, vera++

i've downloaded vera++ 1.2.1 for windows on my pc and run the installation routine, i set also path. now the commandline-prompts
vera++ foo.cpp
don't work(error: cannot open profile description for profile default).
Other prompts don't work either.
Someone an idea what i'm missing.
Thanks in advance and bye

Comment: Try PVS-Studio http://www.viva64.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution based upon it's wiki and it's working for me

you have to set environment variable static where is veera's setup directory located.

I used command : export VERA_ROOT=/usr/local/lib/vera++

Answer (score 0):

vera++ 1.2.1 is over a year old. In April I contributed changes to improve how vera++ works on Microsoft Windows. Can you build from source? If so, this may be helpful.

The change I made is as follows: "Vera++ is now relocatable. It no longer depends on a compile time constant to find the vera installation directory."

If you can build from source and you are still getting the error, just let me know. If you cannot build from source, let me know and I will see what I can do.